# Is it possible to reuse generic types in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I would like to do something like:

```
namepace Namespace<S,T,U,V> {
  type A = doSomething(S, T, U, V);
  type B<X> = doSomethingB(type<A>, V, X);

  interface I<X, Y> {
     a: A;
     b: B<X>
  }
}
```

Basically I want to reuse generic arguments instead of repeating them everytime. I don't want to have to do something like:

```
type A<S, T, U, V> = doSomething(S, T, U, V);
type B<S, T, U, V, X> = doSomething(A<S, T, U, V>, V, X);

interface I<S, T, U, V, X> {
  a: A<S, T, U, V>;
  b: A<S, T, U, V, X>;
}
```

Another way to describe this is the equivalent of a nested `typedef` in C++:

```
template <typename T>
class Abc<T> {
  template <typename U>
  typedef myType<U> = MyFunctor<T, U>;
}

// This works
Abc<T>::myType<U> x;
```

As per @jcalz here is a self-contained example of the problem. Can't really make it minimal because the point is to have many types. What bothers me is all the `type` definitions, especially the helpers at the end, reusing the same arguments.

```
type BaseEngine<Player> = {players: Player[]}

export type CommandStruct<
  Phase extends string,
  MoveName extends string,
  Player,
  Engine extends BaseEngine<Player> = BaseEngine<Player>,
  AvailableCommandData extends BaseCommandData<MoveName> = BaseCommandData<MoveName>,
  CommandData extends BaseCommandData<MoveName> = BaseCommandData<MoveName>,
> = {
  [phase in Phase]?: {
    [move in MoveName]?: {
      available: (engine: Engine, player: Player) => _AvailableCommandHelper<MoveName, AvailableCommandData, move>,
      valid?: (move: _CommandHelper<MoveName, CommandData, move>, available: _AvailableCommandHelper<MoveName, AvailableCommandData, move>) => boolean
    }
  }
}

export type BaseCommandData<MoveName extends string> = {[key in MoveName]?: any};

export type AvailableCommands<MoveName extends string, AvailableCommandData extends BaseCommandData<MoveName>, PlayerId = number> = {
  [move in MoveName]: _AvailableCommand<MoveName, AvailableCommandData, move, PlayerId>;
}

export type AvailableCommand<MoveName extends string, AvailableCommandData extends BaseCommandData<MoveName>, PlayerId = number> = AvailableCommands<MoveName, AvailableCommandData, PlayerId>[MoveName];

type _CommandHelper<MoveName extends string, CommandData extends BaseCommandData<MoveName>, move extends MoveName> = move extends keyof CommandData ? CommandData[move] : undefined;
type _AvailableCommandHelper<MoveName extends string, AvailableCommandData extends BaseCommandData<MoveName>, move extends MoveName> = move extends keyof AvailableCommandData ? AvailableCommandData[move] | AvailableCommandData[move][] | false : boolean;

type _AvailableCommand<MoveName extends string, AvailableCommandData extends BaseCommandData<MoveName>, move extends MoveName, PlayerId = number> = _CommandHelper<MoveName, AvailableCommandData, move> extends undefined ? {move: move, player: PlayerId} : {move: move, player: PlayerId, data: _AvailableCommandHelper<MoveName, AvailableCommandData, move>};
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe this will be a Typescript 4 feature: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0-beta/#variadic-tuple-types

Comment: Is there any way you could make the second part of your code a [mcve] that doesn't use the invalid `doSomething()` function-like syntax?  That is, pick some actual concrete types you want `A<S, T, U, V>` and `B<S, T, U, V, X>` to be and use those (e.g., `type A<S, T, U, V> = {foo: S, bar: [T, U], baz: B}`).

Comment: Not that I think there's a good answer here; you will likely need to write out all those redundant things.  If `S, T, U` always show up together you might be able to package them into an object type `O extends {S: any, T: any, U: any}`, but nothing will free you from having to drag `O` around.  

Comment: @jcalz here you go.

Comment: @Evert I hope so, but I didn't notice it in the blog post.

Comment: @coyotte508 i linked directly to 'variadic tuple types', which I think is what you are looking for. There's examples with generics too.

Comment: @Evert. How do you mean that coyotte508 should use variadic tuple types?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not seeing anything particularly more convenient than what you're doing.  I think we'd need something like local type alias scopes ([microsoft/TypeScript#23188](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23188)) in order to improve it much.