# Can Typescript generic types be reused in multiple places?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have some code with a complex set of generics that I need to use in multiple places. Is there a way to reuse the same generics in multiple places? Or some other good way to simplify the type definitions in this example:

```js
type OSD<T, V> = { [K in keyof T]?: V };

export interface CommandProps<
    ReqQ extends OSD<ReqQ, string> | undefined,
    ReqH extends OSD<ReqH, string> | undefined,
    ReqB extends OSD<ReqB, unknown> | undefined,
    ResH extends OSD<ResH, string> | undefined,
    ResB extends OSD<ResB, unknown> | undefined,
> {
    queryParametersSchema: ReqQ extends undefined ? undefined : Schema;
    requestHeadersSchema: ReqH extends undefined ? undefined : Schema;
    requestBodySchema: ReqB extends undefined ? undefined : Schema;
    responseHeadersSchema: ResH extends undefined ? undefined : Schema;
    responseBodySchema: ResB extends undefined ? undefined : Schema;
}

export default class Command<
    ReqQ extends OSD<ReqQ, string> | undefined,
    ReqH extends OSD<ReqH, string> | undefined,
    ReqB extends OSD<ReqB, unknown> | undefined,
    ResH extends OSD<ResH, string> | undefined,
    ResB extends OSD<ResB, unknown> | undefined,
> {
    readonly queryParametersSchema: ReqQ extends undefined ? undefined : Schema;
    readonly requestHeadersSchema: ReqH extends undefined ? undefined : Schema;
    readonly requestBodySchema: ReqB extends undefined ? undefined : Schema;
    readonly responseHeadersSchema: ResH extends undefined ? undefined : Schema;
    readonly responseBodySchema: ResB extends undefined ? undefined : Schema;

    constructor(props: CommandProps<ReqQ, ReqH, ReqB, ResH, ResB>, queryParameters: ReqQ, requestHeaders: ReqH, requestBody: ReqB) {
        this.queryParametersSchema = props.queryParametersSchema;
        this.requestHeadersSchema = props.requestHeadersSchema;
        this.requestBodySchema = props.requestBodySchema;
        this.responseHeadersSchema = props.responseHeadersSchema;
        this.responseBodySchema = props.responseBodySchema;
    }

    // ... Other methods that use all of these fields
}
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHkGUBFQXggBwC4EsD2A7AhgG0sgE6oDGy0paW2hAngFAiiQCmLoAFssogM4BcIXsmwkA1ugBuLQgDNc6AO4A6EugC2wAI4BXFsIyZewAGwmAnAFYTAFgDs54MlqJ9JYigC0s9IRItPAHMWTBlST2dXCPRPACMA7ExPdFiAKxYyekj2KGgAHgAVABpQADUAPnhQAG9QAG0AaVBUTFAxFlp0WVACgF0Afn4y0ABfAG56ehYAD0RfZGbMZBlZUXYAYQ11RIATAAVCdD48%20lAz0AAlFi0ARVAZ5cwd3ggYPKvbkuFiTEDKgB9QDonixZC0WDsiqdzh8ABL3aaPZ6vfJwr5EFp-UCA4E7UHgyHQs4fABCCKRL1y72uJJKwLEmCUmABQJBYNChPOl308IeIWRVKuvFh6J%20WJxbIJUK5QrJfKelLesrpmAZTJZuPxHKhlWqRNAiGwyA4Q2%20mImXPULGN6B2poxvwm%20t0Mloexo2Cty0IvEgJA4LG2Qw%20d3lyM17IhoH6rLxkZ2oCGfoD2wt50I1z0wlhLGweJ9ycD2GD115iP5LwjBOjsa1UaT-qLabOGZdwhJttohaD3K0cvLCtr8ZrVY5ieYjdT%20ozvDmRhYObzMl9k%20L3OF5IrQ%20rMdH9YnKewzdAM7nvBYHZ2XdXJd4-Yp27Hu8lY4bh4mI0mMzmhAWcewOi4AsJC4NgvAvJs6jbE8JwytcoYDgKSrwaKmIai%20ELSjCpaboOgqlqhvzoXGUr6qSuFIaiNIqmqijMtij6YWRPIUYqVHCoR4qMZy2F3qxKLUneNGMnRxF1oSurTrmOxYLgtAGkaJqgGajpSXmsnyV6HC2vaYpOlyGbqZgcmgC6dDuoQnrWsu3ZriG-F7gmz4ka%20B5NmpMnGfJrZZsgi75iuh4lloZYPo5I4YQmb7uQZ0kaSemb6Mgl7XkFvb3lu4XOeJ462cehmeSZp5YOe-k2Te66hZlkURS5%2055R58XFfOKW2beGWDll3G5au%20npnFXmmXo5kel6y7BTc%20UDUViXZtJ429rCU1GTNbbJZ2wUkn1ZxqEYRA6GQvgABSIIcfBDJB0H7GdvDUp8i0lKSj08s9d7lCUZluqN1k%20hNJQ%20UlZW-Q9CVrSlm0AJQ1PqXLGqgvDKIaxpVKdRwI0jHDHrDHDw8oWm2ijN149a2k7NtXKgHDCOfRZVneoFRaE2jyg0999MNRT5xU8oANzUuBarkzfA87NfnzQL74w1zOMI7z61XrZQuy6LrW9VLZzc81pXiwz2xKyLs4lQuOsc5zlMywbZ4Xp2isIKjwta9bCtq%20r5u46zlljT6VQe3Ty5Y9LuNy0DLwIMHOsBxrFtyylVQx52x6fvqTDKKnEDGjIoD48ixpGkC56gHguCgF05v6OwYIsLgzz0EnTAAHLoAshm4CZ2CIIguCkO3uAV74ZdDUlhhZC47C24XmC0GMoBAA)

Comment: There's no magic solution as far as I know.  I guess it depends how far you are willing to go to remove redundancy, and what your use cases are.  I could imagine collapsing as far as [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbdldw), but only if you can accept such refactorings as putting your generic type parameters into a single type parameter object `T` (which might make inference bad) and using the `props` passed into `Command`'s constructor *directly* instead of iterating over it, so you'd need to write `command.props.requestBodySchema` instead of `command.requestBodySchema`.

Comment: If any of that is useful to you I could write it up, otherwise I'd say the answer is still "no" since [the last time I looked at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62802664/is-it-possible-to-reuse-generic-types-in-typescript).

Comment: Combining the generic types into one type is what I was looking for. I will try that out and see if there are any consequences related to type inference in my codebase.

Comment: I have tried to apply the suggested changes and there does appear to be a problem related to type inference that I can't figure out. At this point I don't want to sink any more time into trying to improve this.